# TestCafe got Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource after version 2.2.0

Tags: testcafe

I'm testing on my localhost.

When I run test using TestCafe version 2.1.0 and before, the test works fine, but after I use version after 2.2.0, I got this error

```
Failed to load the page at "https://localhost:8080/".
      Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to
      execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
      
      Error details:
      Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "https://localhost:8080/".
```

I tried to use proxy or proxy-bypass, but didn't work. How can I use newer version of TestCafe to run my test?

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue based only on this information. Please share a simple reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works now:

1. Update tatcafe to 3.0.0
2. Run test with `'chrome --ignore-certificate-errors'`