# TestCafe http request resulting in 500 error

Tags: typescript, testcafe

since updating TestCafe my http requests are resulting in 500 error.

Request:

```
 test('PI', async t => {
   const results = await t.request({url: helper.getBaseUrl() + `rest/private/endpoint`});

   await t
     .expect(results.status).eql(401)
     .expect(results.statusText).eql('Unauthorized');
 });
```

packages.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-testcafe": "^3.0.0",
    "testcafe": "^2.2.0",
    "testcafe-angular-selectors": "^0.4.1",
    "testcafe-reporter-html": "^1.4.6",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Described in the initial post

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use TestCafe v2.2.0. Please update to the latest version. If this doesn't help, please share a simple reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated TestCafe to v3.3.0 and now getting a different error:
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at http://localhost:4200/rest/private/endpoint

But the link works when copying over in the browser.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the issue without a simple working app. Perhaps, you should use the `127.0.0.1` domain instead of `localhost`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7753#issuecomment-1578131173). Perhaps, you should run tests with the `--ignore-certificate-errors` browser attribute, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488411/testcafe-got-failed-to-find-a-dns-record-for-the-resource-after-version-2-2-0). Please share a simple working example for further research.